# AtrributeError XX object has no atrribute YY

Tags: python, oop

I've just started learning OOP in Python. Everything was going fine until I tried to init a dictionary.

```
class BikeShop:
    bike_details = []

    def __init__(self, model, rate):
    self.bike = {}
    self.bike[self.model] = rate
    BikeShop.bike_details.append(self.bike)

bike = BikeShop('Harley', '$10/hr')
```

I'm getting this error:
`AttributeError: 'BikeShop' object has no attribute 'model'`. When I remove *self.model* and use only *model* then don't see this error.

I could just initialize *model* and *rate* in **init** and append to list in another method but I want to do it in **init** itself. Am I doing it wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You haven't declared an attribute like bike details yet. The self keyword can be tricky to understand. Basically, you've created a BikeShop class and whenever you declare BikeShop(), you're creating a new BikeShop object. The self keyword is just referring to the new BikeShop object that you created, inside the object itself.

If you want to initialize model and rate inside of init you can either

1. Declare self.model like you did self.bike

```
class BikeShop:
    bike_details = []

    def __init__(self, model, rate):
    self.bike = {} 
    self.model = model #<-- new code here
    self.bike[self.model] = rate
    BikeShop.bike_details.append(self.bike)

bike = BikeShop('Harley', '$10/hr')
```

2. Use default initialization

```
class BikeShop:
    bike_details = []

    def __init__(self, model, rate):
        self.bike = {}
        self.bike[model] = rate
        BikeShop.bike_details.append(self.bike)
    
bike = BikeShop('Harley', '$10/hr')
```

3. Initialize with a dictionary and get a bike rate by accessing the key (**I think this is ideal**)

```
bike_details={'Harley':'$10/hr'}
    
class BikeShop:

    def __init__(self, bike_details):
        self.bike_details = bike_details
        
    def getModelRate(self, model):
        return self.bike_details[model]
    
bs = BikeShop(bike_details)
print(bs.getModelRate('Harley'))
```